# difference in return recursion call and just a recursion call

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am currently writing an inorder traversal for a binary search tree, while, the function I have wrote works correctly, I have a question I about how I am recursively calling this function.

**below is the function I have written and the output is currently correct using this implementation.**

```
 if(root == nullptr)
    return;

inorderDump(root->leftSubtree());
cout << root->value() << endl;
inorderDump(root->rightSubtree());
```

My question is why don't these recursive calls need a return statement? The following function written exactly the same with the return statement does not work.

**below is an example of the same function while using the return statement and not getting the correct output.**

```
 if(root == nullptr)
    return;

return inorderDump(root->leftSubtree());
cout << root->value() << endl;
return inorderDump(root->rightSubtree());
```

So I guess in short what I am trying to say is what is the difference between recursively calling a function with and without the return statement, and when do you chose one over the other?
Thanks!

Below is the sample data I am using to test these recursive functions with.

16000 
24507
64025
99756
114258
163016
196448
198668

Comment: "below is the function I have written" - I see no function definition there.

Comment: Well, in the second one, nothing after `return inorderDump(root->leftSubtree());` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is actually a difference in calling just a recursive statement vs calling it using a return statement. As recursion uses stack to maintain its previous state if we don't use a return statement the current state's output or whatever will not be passed to the previous state therefore there are chances of getting a wrong answer.
If you use return statement then you will basically return current state's output to the previous state present in the recursion stack.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one the program just will travel through all the left subtrees until he find a null value, and do nothing else because the return statement make you go out from the function, so it wont travel through the right subtrees or print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion consists of calling the calling function from the called function.

In order for the recursive calling chain to end, there must be an exit condition.

The question posed suggests that a recursive call is dependent on returning something.  Such is not the case. This is an understandable confusion brought on by the factorial and Fibonacci exercises.

In example 1 above, the recursive output is manifested by the output to std::cout.

In example 2, the double call to return is counter-productive -- because the second return can never be executed -- as the function's thread terminated with the first call.  The fact that example 2 calls itself, does not mean that the second return will be executed.

There are recursive functions, the typical fibonacci problem being the best known, where the function makes two calls to subsequent layers.  However, those two calls are called either as separate calls without a return or as an addition, with the return returning a sum.

Again, recursion does not require that a function return a value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly is your confusion so I will throw a wider net here.

Recursion has nothing to to with returning and all to do with calling.

This is what recursion is:

```
... foo(...)
{
    ...
    ... foo(...)...
    ...
}
```

`foo` is a function taking any number and kind of arguments and returning anything (including `void` aka not returning anything). If somewhere inside `foo` you make a call to `foo` then `foo` is recursive. That's it. This is recursion. A function calling itself.

Your function (the first one) has a `cout` instruction, it will print the current node. `return` would have no purpose.

The problem with the second version is simple: after the recursive call to the left side of the tree the function returns immediately, never reaching the `cout` statement, thus never printing and never doing the right side of the tree recursion.